# IE webbrowsercontrol losing .. in file path of URL

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

When a IE browser control is embedded in a winform and the link on a page contains a relative file path the URL coming into the callback for the navigate event seems to lose "`file:///../../dir/file.htm`" and becomes "`file:///dir/file.htm`"

```
private void OnNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
 // looking at e.Url to see what happens
}
```

Has anyone seen similar problems? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your URL is incorrect. If you want a relative path, just specify a relative path, such as `../../dir/file.htm`. If your URL starts with a protocol specifier, then it's an absolute URL, where a `..` at the start is superfluous, since you're already starting at the root of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

`file:///../../dir/file.htm` is not a valid url.  By definition the URI cannot be relative.

(Hence the 'U' in URI/URL)

I agree with other suggestions here: don't use file:///, just specify the relative path directly.